# Chrome is not running in background

Tags: google-chrome, services

"Continue running background apps" is checked.
There is no Chrome entry in Startup applications. 
This command didn't work:

```
google-chrome --no-startup-window
```

[Everybody is complaining](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=chrome%20background&submit=search) how to disable chrome running in background and I can't enable it. Am I missing something?

Forgot to add that I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Chrome 22.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1)You may try this command **/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window**

2)There's an option in Chrome's preferences to do that. In wrench menu, under the hood section, there's "Background Apps, Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" checkbox.

3)You can try to use Devilspie to help with this command **sudo apt-get install devilspie** and you can get more information here http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-start-applications-minimized.html

Comment: As you can see in my question, I have tried 1) and 2). I don't want to install any third party apps to make this work. I know it worked before and it should work now.

Comment: Can you try  uninstall and re-install it or adding it as a crontab and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. Adding it in crontab is same as adding it to Startup Applications. I wanted to enable this background running because of the faster startup time. I guess I will just keep it running minimized.